# Dynamically style HTML elements with element's attribute no Javascript

Tags: html, css, dynamic

Is something like this possible?

```css
div[id^=red]:hover {
        color: (/red/);
    }
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: This is not possible. CSS does have an `attr()` function which can access the element's attributes, however you can only use it to affect the content property of a before/after pseudo element.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to do this with the html bgcolor attribute? I'm trying to do a hover-over-image-overlay effect. Is there a way to work with the opacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `CSS` only, but if you can edit the `HTML` there are workarounds.

The first option is to add a class that represents a color and style it accordingly, this is not very efficient, but it does the job. Of course, it wont work if your colors are dynamic:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
}
.red:hover {
  background: red;
}
.blue:hover {
  background: blue;
}
.green:hover {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
```

Another tricky solution, since you plan to use `:hover`, is to set the color and override it on the idle state:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
div:not(:hover) {
  background: grey !important;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: red;"></div>
<div style="background: blue;"></div>
<div style="background: #fa8732;"></div>
<div style="background: #bb0099;"></div>
```

Which is more efficient since you can add any color you want in you `HTML` and you don't have to worry for the `CSS`.

Of course this will work for any property.